# php code in jquery click function firing without click

Tags: php, jquery

so `$user->turnon` is always the second value which is "1" when loading page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".turnof").click(function(e){
            var editcase = "<?php $USER->turnon = 0 ;?>";
        });
        $(".turnon").click(function(e){
            var editcase = "<?php $USER->turnon = 1 ;?>";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mh, you do know the PHP source will be parsed before the browser receives it? PHP will set $USER->turnon 1 because it is written there. And in your js variable is literally empty.

Comment: If you want to set the variable depending on click events, you have to do an AJAX request to a script exactly doing that. PHP would never notice what your browser is doing, if you're not telling your server with an AJAX request.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois So i want to edit session variable wich is $USER->turnon, could i do it with javascript??

Comment: Do an AJAX request to a PHP script exactly doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call PHP from a JavaScript function directly like that. PHP code executes on your server, so it will evaluate before the page loads. Your code is the same as...

```
<?php
    $USER->turnon = 0;
    $USER->turnon = 1;
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".turnof").click(function(e){
            var editcase = "";
        });

        $(".turnon").click(function(e){
            var editcase = "";
        });

    });
</script>
```

Since you're not using the `echo` function (or another printing function) in your PHP code, nothing is output to the page, so your click functions will just set your JavaScript variable `editcase` to be the empty string.

On the PHP side of things, you're just setting `$USER->turnon` to be 0, and then immediately changing its value to 1. This happens before the page loads.

You may be looking to perform an AJAX request, which allows you initiate requests to your server from a JavaScript function. The request to your server can be used to execute PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it via Ajax, as stated in the comments.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".turnof").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax.php?turnon=0",
                context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
                alert('success');
            });
        });
        $(".turnon").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax.php?turnon=1",
                context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
                alert('success');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the ajax.php

```
//session start etc..
if (isset($_GET['turnon'])) {
    $USER->turnon = $_GET['turnon'] === '1' ? 1 : 0;
}
```